# Кто знает, как сделать рекламу на кликер? (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Кто знает, как сделать рекламу на кликер?  Вот я ипользую:

```
if (score == 60)
{
    if (Advertisement.IsReady())
    {
        Advertisement.Show("video");
    }
}
```

НО теперь у меня постоянно реклама, тоесть я не могу еще раз на кнопку нажать, сразу же реклама.

Comment: может, вы не увеличиваете значение score ?

Comment: Этот код - часть чего? Что такое `score`? Не надо думать, что здесь все владеют телепатией и сразу поймут, что вы хотели изобразить, когда писали этот код. Качественно заданный вопрос - половина ответа.

Comment: попробуйте написать if (score  >= 60)